# How to display Company in header in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have this view :

```
    model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.Order>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <h2>
```

**display CompanyName**

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Customer
        </th>
        <th>
            EmployeeID
        </th>
        <th>
            OrderDate
        </th>
     </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
        </td>
      </tr>
}

</table>
```

I want to display the CompanyName where I marked in bold. At the moment its being displayed in the foreach loop. However I want that one field which is same for this view to pull the CompanyName and display it in between my headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting

```
@{
    if (Model.Any()) {
        Model.First().Customer.CompanyName
    }
}
```

where your bold text is?